# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [50, 200] in Regression with python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, regression, prediction

I am working with the **regression model** in python. this is my source code.

I created a variable and assign it to days want to **predict** .create a new target column and shifted 'x' units.

```
future_days = 50
df['Prediction'] = df['PriceUSD'].shift(-future_days)
df.tail(4)
```

create a feature dataset and convert it into a numpy array.

```
X = np.array(df.drop(['Prediction'],1))[:future_days]
print(X)
```

create the target dataset y and convert it into NumPy array.after getting all the values.

```
y = np.array(df['Prediction'])[:-future_days]
print(y)
```

split the dataset.

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25)
```

I got an error when splitting the test set.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-34da76684947> in <module>()
----> 1 x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.99)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    210     if len(uniques) > 1:
    211         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 212                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    213 
    214 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [50, 200]
```

Comment: Issue is not reproducible but it seems like your x and y doesn't contain the same number of elements.